# Directional Derivative help, solving for derivative = 0 when given constants

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A function that is useful in studying the air flow over mountains is

$$h(x,y) = \frac{h_0}{[(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2+1]^\frac{3}{2}}
$$

where $h_0$, a, and b are all positive constants.

(a)  Find $\nabla h$.

(b)  Find the directional derivative of the point (x,y) in the direction of the vector $v=(v_1,v_2)$

(c)  At what point(s) is the directional derivative equal to zero?

For part a), I found that $\nabla h$ is equal to 
$$\frac{-3h_0}{[(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2+1]^\frac{5}{2}}\langle\frac{x}{a^2},\frac{y}{b^2}\rangle
$$

Using this, I found that for part b), I got that $D_uh(x,y) = \frac{-3h_0}{[(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2+1]^\frac{5}{2}}\langle\frac{x}{a^2},\frac{y}{b^2}\rangle \bullet\frac{1}{\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}}\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$

which simplifies to $D_uh(x,y) = \frac{-3h_0}{[(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2+1]^\frac{5}{2}{\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}}}(\frac{xv_1}{a^2}+\frac{yv_2}{b^2})$

First of all, is this correct?

Secondly, given that I am correct up to this point, I am unsure on how to do part c). How can I solve for an x and y where $D_uh = 0$ when I do not have values for $v_1$ and $v_2$?

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: I suposse you have to solve the equation $\frac{xv_{1}}{a^{2}}+\frac{yv_{2}}{b^{2}}=0$

Comment: and the vector solution is $(-ya^{2},xb^{2})$, if the vector solution has unit lenght you have to normalize that vector

Comment: @juliogodoy Wouldn't that solution require that $v_1 = -v_2$? if you plug in those x and y values in the equation, you get $-yv_1 + xv_2 = 0$. What am I missing here?

Comment: you can use also the fact that $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular then $u\cdot v = 0$ and if $u = (u_1,u_2)$ then $v=(-u_2,u_1)$

Comment: In that case wouldnt the answer be $(\frac{-yv_2}{b^2},\frac{xv_1}{a^2})$?

*edit: Actually it would be $(\frac{-v_2}{b^2},\frac{v_1}{a^2})$. Is that correct?

Comment: No, you have $v_1 = -u_2$ and $v_2 = u_1$ where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the components of $\nabla h$ and you should express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $v_1$ and $v_2$

Comment: Right, so would my edit in the comment above be correct?

Comment: $v_{1}=\frac{-ya^{2}}{xb^{2}}v_{2}$ then $(v_{1},v_{2})=\left(\frac{-ya^{2}}{xb^{2}}v_{2},v_{2}\right)$ now multiply for $\frac{xb^{2}}{v_{2}}$ we have the result $(-ya^{2},xb^{2})$, exploting the fact that the multiplication of a scalar into a vector don`t change their direction...Sorry for my english

Comment: @juliogodoy: The question ask for the point so you should find $x$ and $y$

Comment: @dubbler26 how did you get that answer?

Comment: @Navaro just by doing what you said. I've trying to find the vector $\langle x,y \rangle$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle \bullet \langle \frac{v_1}{a^2},\frac{v_2}{b^2} \rangle = 0$.

Therefore $\langle x,y \rangle$ should equal $\langle \frac{-v_2}{b^2},\frac{v_1}{a^2} \rangle.$ Right?

Comment: i think, for answer this question $x$ and $y$ should be given.

Comment: @Sorry you misunderstood me, the answer in fact is: a straight line given by the equation $c_1x+c_2y = 0$ where $c_1 = v_1/a^2$ and $c_2 = v_2/b^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two answers are correct.

For the third question: the directional derivative is equal to $0$ if $v =(v_1,v_2)$ is perpendicular to $\nabla h$ , so:
$$v\cdot \nabla h = 0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{v_1}{a^2}x+\dfrac{v_2}{b^2}y = 0 \Rightarrow y = -\left( \dfrac{b}{a} \right)^2\left(\dfrac{v_1}{v_2}\right)x\Rightarrow y=cx \quad\text{where } c=-\left( \dfrac{b}{a} \right)^2\left(\dfrac{v_1}{v_2}\right)$$
which is the equation of a straight line passing through the origin $O=(0,0)$

**conclusion:** every point $(x,y)$ satisfying the previous equation makes the directional derivative in the direction of $v=(v_1,v_2)$ equal to zero

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The condition $x\frac{v_1}{a^2}+y\frac{v_2}{b^2}=0$ could be written $(P-O)\cdot\mathbf{u}=0$, where $P=(x,y)$, $O=(0,0)$ and $\mathbf{u}=\langle\frac{v_1}{a^2},\frac{v_2}{b^2}\rangle$.
This is the equation of the straight line passing through $O$ and orthogonal to $\mathbf{u}$.

The directional derivative is $0$ on each point of this line.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Why is it (P-O)? What does P represent? How would I present my answer for part c) then?

Comment: @dubbler26: edited.